# Why is $\Bbb R\setminus\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ not locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have a question: if I take in $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ the set $A=\left\{\frac1n, n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ and I consider the set $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus A$

I want to prove that $B$ is not locally compact, we have that $0\in B$ is there a compact which contains the open $]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[,\forall\varepsilon>0$ ?

Thank you

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is 'Is there a compact set containing $0$?'  The answer is 'yes' (Exercise: show that there is a compact neighbourhood of any point $x$ of $B$ such that $x\ne 0$ - so if $B$ is not locally compact, then the point $0\in B$ must have no compact neighbourhood.)

Comment: the professor told us that there is no compact neighborhood of 0 and i don't know why

Answer (score 4):

If $B$ were locally compact, then $0\in B$ would have a relative neighborhood in $B$, that is, a set $N\cap B$ where $N$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$, such that $N\cap B$ is compact. Now $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, so this $N\cap B$ would have to be closed. Can you show that no such set is closed?

Comment: no i don't see why

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Assume $N$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. Then for some $\varepsilon>0$, we have $[0,\varepsilon)\subset N$. Now there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $1/n<\varepsilon$. Can you show that $1/n$ is a limit point of $N\cap B$?

Comment: i don't understand no , there is no esear ?

Comment: I don't think there's an easier argument. If you don't see why $N\cap B$ is not closed, draw or picture, or try to visualize the involved sets.

Comment: i still don't understand

Comment: we have that $0\in]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[\subset[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$, $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ is compact no ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, $[-ε,ε]$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$. But $[-ε,ε]$ is not a subset of $B$, so it is not a neighborhood of $0$ **in the subspace** $B$. However, $[-ε,ε]\cap B$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $B$, but this relative neighborhood is not compact.

Comment: if we prove that $(B,|.|)$ is not separted i.e $\exists x\neq y,\forall V\in \mathcal{V}(x), U\in\mathcal{U}(y), U\cap V\neq \emptyset$ then $B$ is not locally compact

Comment: please 0 is the only point who makes problem ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes $0$ is the only point without a compact neighborhood in $B$.

Comment: and prove that $(B,|.|)$ is not separated ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: $B$ is separated (I assume by that you mean Hausdorff) because it's a subspace of a separated space $\Bbb R$.